# What permissions are needed to copy databases in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I wrote a little app to backup SQL Azure databases using the very usefull 'CREATE AS COPY OF' command in SQL Azure.  e.g.

```
CREATE DATABASE MyNewDB AS COPY OF MyOldDB
```

I run this command with the admin login (first login you get when creating a server).  **My Question: What are the minimal permissions a new login would need to execute the above command?**

So far here's what I've done:

```
-- IN MASTER DB --
CREATE LOGIN DBCreator WITH PASSWORD = '?????????????'
CREATE USER DBCreator FROM LOGIN DBCreator;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbmanager', 'DBCreator';

-- IN MyOldDB --
-- (I ran this stuff when the previous commands didn't do it) --
CREATE USER DBCreator FROM LOGIN DBCreator;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'DBCreator';  --
```

And the result when running the above CREATE DATABASE command:

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'MyOldDB'.
```

Comment: Hi - you need to be connected to master when you run the CREATE DATABASE command. Also make sure the account you use is part of the dbmanager database role (in master); this is the permission you need.  Here is the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336274.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm running the Create Database command from 'master'.  Yes, the new login is dbmanager in master.

Comment: I tried your steps, and also added DBCreator as a db_owner of the source database. I got the same error. Then I remembered that there was an additional restriction... basically the user issuing the CREATE DATABASE statement must be the "original" user that created the source database.

Comment: ... "Only the login that created the source database, the DBO, can copy the database to another database". Here is the link that talks about that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951631.aspx

Comment: Thanks Herve.  I think the key, as you said, is that the copier user needs to be the one that created the DB.  To further confirm this, I tested adding the DBCreator to the owners group of MyOldDB and was still not able to get it to work.  Maybe the Azure team will add a specific role for doing these backup copies, or even the ability to schedule the task.

Comment: There's one more issue that might cause this problem: a spelling error. If you misspell the name of 'MyOldDB' you'll get this error message.

Answer (score 1):

I could not add the db_owner role to new login, the command

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'NewLogin'
```

throws the error

`Cannot alter the role 'db_owner', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

But using the dbmanager role works

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbmanager', 'NewLogin'
```

There is useful information in the article [Managing Databases and Logins in Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336235.aspx).

Comment: Is there any other less-permissive role than db_owner? I'd like a set of employees to be able to copy a database but not to be able to write to it.